# Most beautiful open source software written in c++

Tags: c++

I was told that to be a good developer, you should read a lot of other peoples source code. I think that sounds reasonable. So I ask you, what is the most beautifully written piece of open source software that is written in c++ out there?

(Apply any definition of beautiful you like.)

Comment: this is bound to get closed as either subjective or not a real question. so don't take it hard.

Comment: @Assaf Well, he could mark it as a community wiki... just a thought.

Comment: Hi. I am simply asking for suggestions on source code to read for inspiration, using specific technologies that I am interested in. Why would that get closed?

Comment: I agree on the community wiki... bjakef, you should click the edit button at the bottom of your question, and click the check box marked "community wiki" and save it... otherwise this will very likely be closed

Comment: "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder", or so they say... we generally don't like subjective questions on SO, though marking them as community wiki generally appeases people.

Comment: Beauty? C++? ... can't think of any :P

Comment: Perl, now there's a beautiful language... or aleternatively, a mind breaker, probably in equal portions...

Comment: I think this is a pretty valid question... I have yet to see C++ code that didn't look like someone had vomited on it in some places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the source code of MySQL GUI Tools. Its written using gtkmm, and the code does some interesting difficult-to-implement GUI things.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO...

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Tou should take a look at the source code of [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/). It's really clear and well documented.

Comment: I've heard nice things about the NetBSD source, but I think the question is specifically about about C++ source.

Answer (score 2):

It think "Qt"

Answer (score 2):

Qt creates beautiful GUIs. Code in C++ and you get awesome screens! But I think the OP has asked for some good C++ code repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Loki is a pretty nice library especially if you're interested in how design patterns and various idioms are expressed in C++.  Reading the source might also be a good way to understand C++'s metaprogramming facility using templates.

http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check the [arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) browser sources. It shows the beauty of the Qt toolkit and elegant and well written code for a somewhat complex application.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that Google's Chromium source code is very clean.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the [Poco C++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org) is very neat as well.